# VBScript to get DC SYSVOL information (path, size, free space)

Tags: vbscript, ldap, wmi, wmi-query, ldap-query

I am obtaining information about my DCs and need to pull in the path to sysvol, total size, and free space remaining.

Cant his be done in VBScript and if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814167) - the registry entries are in this document of where the SYSVOL and other NTDS directories are stored.

You might find that you can also get this information through Active Directory however I'm not sure - I will check ADSIEdit shorly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the WMI. See an example here: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_disks.htm

Comment: Not really helping me. Just not finding out how to query for the fRSRootPath.

Comment: Can you explain what you really need. What do you mean by DC, I guess you do not have multiple Data Centers? What did you try? Later on I saw you tagged this question with WMI, so you have experience with that.

Comment: I need the frsrootpath of the sysvol share on the domain controllers in my forest so that I can query the same machine to find out the disk space that sysvol sits on (total and free).

Comment: I know how to query the hard disk and obtain the information I need, I just have to make sure the partition I am obtaining the info from is where the sysvol share is sitting.